# Microsoft outlook 365 actionable message

Tags: json, outlook, office365

Hi would like to know why my actionable message will not appear on mobile but on the web it will appear perfectly. Anyone know what is the problem i'm facing?

Below are the script that i'm putting.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@type": "MessageCard",
        "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
        "summary": "This is the summary property",
        "themeColor": "0075FF",
        "sections": [{
                "heroImage": {
                    "image": "http://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/assets/FlowLogo.png"
                }
            },
            {
                "startGroup": true,
                "title": "**Pending approval**",
                "activityImage": "http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/MSC12_Oscar_002.jpg",
                "activityTitle": "Requested by **Miguel Garcia**",
                "activitySubtitle": "m.garcia@contoso.com",
                "facts": [{
                        "name": "Date submitted:",
                        "value": "06/27/2017, 2:44 PM"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Details:",
                        "value": "Please approve the awesome changes I made to this fantastic document."
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Link:",
                        "value": "[Link to the awesome document.pptx](http://www.google.com)"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "potentialAction": [{
                        "@type": "ActionCard",
                        "name": "Approve",
                        "inputs": [{
                            "@type": "TextInput",
                            "id": "comment",
                            "isMultiline": true,
                            "title": "Reason (optional)"
                        }],
                        "actions": [{
                            "@type": "HttpPOST",
                            "name": "Submit",
                            "target": "http://..."
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "ActionCard",
                        "name": "Reject",
                        "inputs": [{
                            "@type": "TextInput",
                            "id": "comment",
                            "isMultiline": true,
                            "title": "Reason (optional)"
                        }],
                        "actions": [{
                            "@type": "HttpPOST",
                            "name": "Submit",
                            "target": "http://..."
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "startGroup": true,
                "activitySubtitle": "Grant approvals directly from your mobile device with the Microsoft Flow app. [Learn more](http://learnmode)\n\nThis message was created by an automated workflow in Microsoft Flow. Do not reply."
            }
        ]
    }

</script>
```

If i open my Outlook mobile app, There will be no card shown, but only on outlook web. Does actionable message does not support mobile currently?

Regards,

Khairul Ezwan B. Mohd Kaswan

Comment: Have you found a resolution to your issue or any additional information? Is this feature only supported via OWA?

Comment: Yes is do.Apparently the feature only supported via OWA.

Comment: I was able to have it work on the desktop client by moving from the deferred channel to the targeted channel. It looks like support comes some time between version 1705 and 1710. No idea about the mobile app, but it looks like support is coming for desktop.